# How to handle image not found error in Glide V4

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I tried to handle image not found (404) error in Glide, but it doesn't compile :

```
Glide.with(this@ImageActivity)
                        .addDefaultRequestListener(
                                object:RequestListener<Drawable> {
                                    override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                                        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                                    }

                                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                                        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                                    }

                                }

                        )
                        .load(imageURL).apply(requestOptions)
                        .into(imageview)
```

But compiler raises this error on **object:RequestListener** :

> Type mismatch: inferred type is  but
>   RequestListener! was expected

Comment: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html#error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `addDefaultRequestListener`, you need to use `Any` instead of `Drawable`

```
Glide.with(context).addDefaultRequestListener(object : RequestListener<Any> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Any>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Any?, model: Any?, target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Any>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            }

        })
```

Comment: Why thought? isn't it just a type parameter? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use submit() like this -

```
Glide.with(this@ProfileActivity).load(imageURL).into(imageview)
              .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                  override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                      //TODO handle error images while loading photo
                      return true
                  }

                  override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                      //TODO use "resource" as the photo for your ImageView
                      return true
                  }

              }).submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Glide simply with `placeholder()` method. You can use the following method.

```
private fun fetchImage(imageView: ImageView, url: String){
    Glide
        .with(this)
        .load(url)
        .centerCrop()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
        .into(imageView)
}
```

Comment: No error drawable is not enough, I want to do something in case of 404 error.

Comment: Oh, then you can follow the answer given by @bach-vu :)